# python pandas fill NaN or blanket with max value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with a big data frame. Here is a small snippet. I want to fill the last columns E with the maximal value, if there ist some value or let it empty. That is the data:

```
d = {'A': [4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074,
   4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074],
 'B': ['SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746','SP000796746',
   'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 
   'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746'],
 'C': [201926, 201926, 201926, 201926, 201926, 201926, 201909,201909, 201909, 201909, 201909, 
   201909, 201933, 201933, 201933, 201933, 201933, 201933],
 'D': [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 'E': [np.nan, 1000, 1000, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3000, 3000, np.nan]}
```

it looks like this:

```
       A            B       C     D       E
0   4000074  SP000796746  201926 -1     NaN
1   4000074  SP000796746  201926  0  1000.0
2   4000074  SP000796746  201926  1  1000.0
3   4000074  SP000796746  201926  2     NaN
4   4000074  SP000796746  201926  3     NaN
5   4000074  SP000796746  201926  4     NaN
6   4000074  SP000796746  201909 -1     NaN
7   4000074  SP000796746  201909  0     NaN
8   4000074  SP000796746  201909  1     NaN
9   4000074  SP000796746  201909  2     NaN
10  4000074  SP000796746  201909  3     NaN
11  4000074  SP000796746  201909  4     NaN
12  4000074  SP000796746  201933 -1     NaN
13  4000074  SP000796746  201933  0     NaN
14  4000074  SP000796746  201933  1     NaN
15  4000074  SP000796746  201933  2  3000.0
16  4000074  SP000796746  201933  3  3000.0
17  4000074  SP000796746  201933  4     NaN
```

But my target is to fill column "E" every where with the highest value, if there
is any value between the range -1 to 4 (column D).if not it should remain empty. So it should look like:

```
      A            B       C      D       E
0   4000074  SP000796746  201926 -1       0
1   4000074  SP000796746  201926  0  1000.0
2   4000074  SP000796746  201926  1  1000.0
3   4000074  SP000796746  201926  2       0
4   4000074  SP000796746  201926  3       0
5   4000074  SP000796746  201926  4       0
6   4000074  SP000796746  201909 -1     NaN
7   4000074  SP000796746  201909  0     NaN
8   4000074  SP000796746  201909  1     NaN
9   4000074  SP000796746  201909  2     NaN
10  4000074  SP000796746  201909  3     NaN  
11  4000074  SP000796746  201909  4     NaN
12  4000074  SP000796746  201933 -1  3000.0
13  4000074  SP000796746  201933  0  3000.0
14  4000074  SP000796746  201933  1  3000.0
15  4000074  SP000796746  201933  2  3000.0
16  4000074  SP000796746  201933  3  3000.0
17  4000074  SP000796746  201933  4  3000.0
```

My code looks like this:

```
df = d

indx = df[df['D'] == -1].index.values

for i, j in zip(indx[:-1], indx[1:]):
        df.loc[i:j-1, 'E'] = df.loc[i:j-1, 'E'].max()

if j == indx[-1]:
            df.loc[j:, 'E'] = df.loc[j:, 'E'].max()
```

It does not work for very big data frames... Maybe somebody has an idea
for another code or a correction in my code.

Thank you!!

```
      A            B       C      D       E
0   4000074  SP000796746  201926 -1       0
1   4000074  SP000796746  201926  0  1000.0
2   4000074  SP000796746  201926  1  1000.0
3   4000074  SP000796746  201926  2       0
4   4000074  SP000796746  201926  3       0
5   4000074  SP000796746  201926  4       0
6   4000074  SP000796746  201909 -1     NaN
7   4000074  SP000796746  201909  0     NaN
8   4000074  SP000796746  201909  1     NaN
9   4000074  SP000796746  201909  2     NaN
10  4000074  SP000796746  201909  3     NaN  
11  4000074  SP000796746  201909  4     NaN
12  4000074  SP000796746  201933 -1       0
13  4000074  SP000796746  201933  0       0
14  4000074  SP000796746  201933  1       0
15  4000074  SP000796746  201933  2  3000.0
16  4000074  SP000796746  201933  3  3000.0
17  4000074  SP000796746  201933  4       0
```

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over dataframes using for loops.
Probably thats the reason why it doesnt work with big dataframes. Check out this very good post on GeeksForGeeks about iteration over dataframes: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with `groupby.transform` the `max` of the groups made with a new -1 in column D and `cumsum`. Then `fillna` the original column.

```
df['E'] = df['E'].fillna(df['E'].groupby(df['D'].eq(-1).cumsum()).transform('max'))
```

EDIT: to fill with zeros, you can do it:

```
mask = df['E'].groupby(df['D'].eq(-1).cumsum()).transform('any')
df.loc[mask, 'E'] = df.loc[mask, 'E'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: yes it works, thank you very much. Can I do the same, if I want to fill it instead with zeros? So the the values stay the same, but around them the empty places were filled with "0"? I added another table how it should look like, at the end of the post

Comment: @Hanna see my edit, it is slightly different but based on the same groupby.transform idea, but with `any` to find groups with at least one non nan value in it